# Ubuntu 13.04 Scrolling not precise enough, jumps whole pages

Tags: mouse

Each increment of my wireless mouse's scroll wheel jumps an entire screen worth, this occurs throughout the entirety of Ubuntu, I only got it today just trying to get everything working I am not an expert in coding etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i'm aware there isn't any graphical way to alter your mouse scroll speed across the entire system so we have to change it at the input device through xorg.

First we find the name of our mouse device whose settings we wish to change

```
xinput --list
```

with the name and id of the device we can find out what properties your device has that we can play around with

```
xinput --list-props id
```

where id is the id of your mouse input device.

Hopefully you see a bunch of properties and their values. You are looking got the `Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia` property. Contrary to other systems the higher the value the slower your scroll speed will be. You can alter this by running:

```
xinput set-int-prop "device id" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia" 16 5
```

Where device id is the id of your device. And then alter the integer "5" at the end. 16 is required for some formatting purposes, just alter the last integer.